# Using chain and combinations_with_replacement commands to transform values in arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have a dataset containing multiple arrays that each have 2 values.

I want to make a function that takes in input (dataset,degree), and performs some transformations on each array. Namely, for an array [x,y], I want to return a new array [1, x, y, xy, (x^2)y, x(y^2), ... , (x^degree)y, x(y^degree).

I'm trying to use **chain** to return all the sub arrays as one array, then I will apply the necessary transformations on that one array, and then I will use **combinations_with_replacement** to make the one transformed array back to the sub arrays.

If my question isn't clear, an example of the function would be f(([1,2], [3,4]), 2). This would return ([[1,1,2,2,2,4], [1,3,4,12,36,48]]).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the pattern in the output. It seems the first elements are `x**0 * y**0`, `x**1 * y**0`, `x**0 * y**1`, `x**1 * y**1`, `x**2 * y**1`, and `x**1 * y**2`, but then why doesn't the sequence include `x**2 * y**2`? What if the degree was `3`, would `x**3 * y**2` be one of the expected outputs?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well. If the degree was 3,  (x^3)(y^2) wouldn't be one of the expected outputs. However, (x^3)y, and x(y^3) would.

Comment: If the degree was 4, (x^4)y and x(y^5) would be part of the expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this produces exactly the output you expect, but it should be pretty close:

```
def powers(x, y, degree): # we'll assume degree >= 1
    result= [1, x, y, x*y]
    for i in range(2, degree+1):
        result.append(x**i *y)
        result.append(y**i *x)
    return result

def f(arrays, degree):
    return [powers(arr[0], arr[1], degree) for arr in arrays]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Any idea on how to implement using combinations_with_replacement and chain?

Comment: @itstoocold No, I think those functions would probably make this needlessly complicated.